# ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 5>" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-integration

I'm trying to invoke a function/stored procedure of PostgreSQL (which returns a cursor). I'm invoking the function via `stored-proc-outbound-gateway` of Spring Integration. It gives me below error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: @sampleProcedureGateway.exchange(#root).payload; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call erb.getSampleDetails_sp(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [34000]; error code [0]; ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 5>" does not exist; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 5>" does not exist
```

Below is my Spring Integration config:

```
<int:chain input-channel="inputDataChannel">
    <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway data-source="dataSource" expect-single-result="true" is-function="true" stored-procedure-name="erb.getSampleDetails_sp" ignore-column-meta-data="true">
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="id" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="date" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="name" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="endrow" type="INTEGER" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="startrow" type="INTEGER" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="finalData" direction="OUT"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="id" expression="headers.xxx.yyy.id"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="date" expression="headers['documentDate']"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="name" expression="headers['isCondition']"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="endrow" expression="headers['endRow']"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="startrow" expression="headers['startRow']"/> 
        <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="finalData" row-mapper="sampleRowMapper" />
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>                                                        
</int:chain>
```

Below is the Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION erb.getSampleDetails_sp(
id text,
date text,
name text,
endrow double precision,
startrow double precision,
OUT finalData refcursor)
    RETURNS refcursor
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
    IF name = 'true' THEN
        OPEN finalData FOR
        SELECT
            *
            FROM (SELECT
                row_number() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS rnum, vhinv.*
                FROM (SELECT query) AS vhinv
                LIMIT i_endrow) AS var_sbq
            WHERE rnum >= i_startrow;
    ELSE
        OPEN finalData FOR
        SELECT
            *
            FROM (SELECT
                row_number() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) AS rnum, vhinv.*
                FROM (SELECT query) AS vhinv
                LIMIT i_endrow) AS var_sbq_2
            WHERE rnum >= i_startrow;
    END IF;
END;

$BODY$;
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: did u solved the issue i'm facing same thing

Answer (score 0):

First of all you really need to be sure that stored procedure is really function (`is-function="true"`) and it returns cursor.

Would be great to see your stored procedure to be sure that you map all the arguments properly.

There is also a description in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#sp-common-config-subelements):

> Specifies the direction of the SQL parameter definition. Defaults to `IN`. Valid values are: `IN`, `OUT` and `INOUT`. If your procedure is returning `ResultSets`, please use the `returning-resultset` element. Optional.

I mean that you have to remove `sql-parameter-definition name="finalData"` from your configuration and just rely on the `returning-resultset name="finalData"`.

Comment: Yes. All the SPs in Postgres are declared as function. I've tried removing  sql-parameter-definition name="finalData". But still am getting the same error. Edited question with Stored procedure content. (Without including the actual Select queries)

Comment: You have to edit your question and show the procedure

Comment: Edited the question with Stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed after setting autoCommit to false in Datasource bean definition.

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);
dataSource.setUrl(dbConnectionUrl);
dataSource.setUsername(userName);
dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
dataSource.setEnableAutoCommitOnReturn(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Abirmi mentioned it should be fixed by setting `AutoCommit` to false at the same time we should follow the below approach instead of hardcoding it if you are fixing this issue in the mid of existing large applications. Hence we can be sure that we are altering the AutoCommit property only for the required flow instead of entire operations of that connection object involved.

```java
boolean default_autocommit = false;
try {
    connection = // consider getting connection object here
    default_autocommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    ...
    ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
    connection.setAutoCommit(default_autocommit);
    }
```